# GridView in Windows Phone8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am new in windows phone apps development.I wanted to know that how can I create a Gridview in my app.As I have to display  values coming from json in each cell.And once you click on any of the cell,it would do an Http Post.

Comment: Hope this answers your question http://goo.gl/Tir5pa

Answer (score 1):

Bob Tabor, the author of this video tutorial series for wp8 has an interesting app that gets images using Flickr's api and populates images in a grid format where it is populated by images from the search result.

Here's the link: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-27-Navigating-and-Passing-Data-to-the-SearchResults-Page

Answer (score 0):

There is a great series from Channel9 on Windows Phone 8.
Layout like grid view is explained in this episode:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-5-Basics-of-Layout-and-Events

I did non explore json, but if you are looking for basics on layout (like gridview), this tutorial may be very useful.